# Using promises in react-redux actions dispatch functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react-redux . I want to know is this ok to use ES6 promises with actions dispatch functions ? Suppose i want to show success toast after request success . What i did is resolve promise when request hit successfully.See example code below

```
#Example

function login(credentials){
return dispatch => {
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
     dispatch(login_request);
     service.login(credentials)
                .then(
                 (data)=> { 
                 dispatch(login_success,data);
                 resolve();
})

}) }}
```

Then calling that function from UI what i did,

```
login().then(success => show_toast());
```

Is this approach OK to show toast?

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's fine, though personally i think its unnecessary to chain to this promise.
You already dispatching an action inside your thunk `login_success`, so you can use this as a condition to show the toast

Comment: I don't get it . Can u please be more clear about that with some dry code .